# Call function in react to get API data from componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs

I am not able to fetch data from API using a function being called from `componentDidMount`.

What I am trying to do is get the data from an API using a `getData()`, but I don't understand how to call it from `componentDidMount` .

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class AJAX extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       quote: ""
     };
   }

   getData = async () => {
      console.log("Inside getData");
      const data = await axios.get("https://api.github.com/zen");
      return data;
   };

   async componentDidMount() {
      console.log("inside compo");
      let data1 = await this.getData();
      console.log(data1);
   }

   render() {
      return (
        <h1>"Hello"</h1>
      );
   }
}

export default AJAX;
```

Error: I am getting is this

```sh
Request failed with status code 403
```

Comment: either method you're doing is fine; the error response is telling you the issue which is that it returns status code 403 which means you need authorize with the api before doing any requests so you probably have to supply a key/token in the request well

Answer (score 0):

The given error is about authorization.
you must authorize to call api.
for authorization, you must pass the token parameter like this:

```
const token = '..your token..'

axios.post(url, {
  //...data
}, {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${token}` 
  }
})
```

Comment: No Buddy its open source and free.

Comment: The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error status response code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.

This status is similar to 401, but in this case, re-authenticating will make no difference. The access is permanently forbidden and tied to the application logic, such as insufficient rights to a resource.